# spark date_format showing null in version 2.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert date format. I have data like below in one column:

```
04-JUN-21 09.07.55.061067 PM
```

I am trying to convert it into below format:

```
2021-06-04 21:07:55
```

I am trying below code to do this:

```
val df = Seq("04-JUN-21 09.07.55.061067 PM", "05-JUN-21 09.07.55.061067 PM").toDF("UPLOADED_DATE")
df.select(date_format(to_timestamp($"UPLOADED_DATE","dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as "UPLOADED_DATE").show
df.registerTempTable("tbl")
spark.sql("select date_format(to_timestamp(UPLOADED_DATE,'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as UPLOADED_DATE from tbl").show()
```

I am getting result when using spark 3.0.2 version:

```
+-------------------+
|      UPLOADED_DATE|
+-------------------+
|2021-06-04 21:07:55|
|2021-06-05 21:07:55|
+-------------------+
```

But getting null when using spark 2.4.7 version:

```
+-------------+
|UPLOADED_DATE|
+-------------+
|         null|
|         null|
+-------------+
```

Kindly let me know if there is a different way to do it in spark 2.4 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround. It seems the milliseconds part of the timestamp is causing issues, so if you're going to discard it anyway, you can remove it before calling `to_timestamp`:

```
df.select(
    date_format(
        to_timestamp(
            regexp_replace($"UPLOADED_DATE", "\\.\\d{6}", ""),
            "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss a"
        ),
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    ) as "UPLOADED_DATE"
).show
+-------------------+
|      UPLOADED_DATE|
+-------------------+
|2021-06-04 21:07:55|
|2021-06-05 21:07:55|
+-------------------+
```